# How does this loop work? I am unable to understand it

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, increment

```cpp
for(int i=1;i<=n;){
    f++;
    if((i++==p) || (i++==p))
        break;
}
```

example1 : `n=7,p=3,f=0`; so the value of `f` should be 1, right? But it is giving `f=2` as output

example2 : `n=7,p=4,f=0`; it is giving output as `f=2`

example3 : `n=7,p=5,f=0`; it is giving output as `f=3`

Help me understanding this.

Comment: You might be in undefined behavior territory with two instances of the postfix operator on the same variable within the same expression.

Comment: The output looks correct to me.  Write down your variables on paper, hold your finger on each statement in the loop, and run the thing by hand.  Update the relevant variable each time.  Remember that when you use postfix-increment (`i++`) then the value returned is the value _before_ being incremented.

Comment: @selbie That doesn't seem right. The left hand operator to `||` has to be evaluated before the right hand operator to enable short circuiting, so there's no sequencing ambiguity.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where anyone could use this. It doesn't seem of much use, since i is local in scope. If i was used as an index of a string, then `if((i++==p) || (i++==p))` would give the very next available position at the end of the break if it wasn't local. Additionally, incrementing this way will violate the `i<=n`, making it difficult to figure out how large i can be.

Comment: @placidchat -- you're right that the code is confusing, but there's nothing inherently bad about modifying the loop index (`i`) in the loop body. You could, for example, write a `for` loop without an increment in the `for`: `for (int i =0; i < n; ) { ++i; }`. Sometimes that's handy. In this case, because of the way that the increments are buried in that `if` statement, it's pretty much unreadable.

Comment: Whoever wrote that code should be immediately fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1** When `n=7,p=3,f=0` . Lets look at values of different variables while going through the for loop.

**Iteration 1**

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;) //here n = 7
{
   f++; //here f becomes 1 that is now we have f = 1
   if((i++==p) || (i++==p)) // variable i is incremented by 1 and becomes 2 because of the 
   //first i++. But note the old value of i(which is 1) is returned by i++. So although 
   //right now i = 2, its old value(which is 1) is compared with the value of variable 
   //p(which is 3). Since 1 and 3 are not equal the next (i++==p) is evaluated. And so 
   //again variable i is incremented and becomes 3. But here also the old value of 
   //i(which is 2) is used to compare with value of variable p(which is still 3). But since
   //2 is not equal to 3 the control flow doesn't go inside the `if` and so `break` is not 
   //executed.

   break;
}
```

**Iteration 2**

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;) //here n = 7
{
   f++; //here f becomes 2 that is now we have f = 2
   if((i++==p) || (i++==p)) // Now i is incremented again because of the first i++ and 
   //becomes 4. But here also the old value of variable i(which is 3) is used to compare 
   //with value of variable p(which is 3) and since 3 = 3 the condition is satisfied 
   //and we go inside the `if` statement and `break` is executed. Note at this point 
   //the value of f is 2 .That is why you get f =2 as output.

   break;
}
```

Similarly you can work out for Case 2 where `n=7,p=4,f=0;` .

Note that you can/should use the **debugger** for this purpose.